# Basic matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A$ is a square matrix satisfying $A^2=A$, and $B$ any matrix of the same size as $A$, show that
$$(AB-ABA)^2=0.$$

Tried to expand and solve, and also tried to show $AB=ABA$ with the information given, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding $(AB-ABA)^2$, we have
$$
(AB-ABA)^2 = ABAB + ABAABA - ABABA - ABAAB  
$$
$$ 
  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \    = ABAB + ABABA - ABABA - ABAB = 0
$$
The first equality is direct expansion, the second equality is due to $ABAABA = ABABA$ and $ABAAB = ABAB$.